How to quickly determine if A - (A ∩ (ΣBi)) set exists and pick a random value from it?
I am trying to make my code randomly and quickly find a point (x,y) in the A disc, which is not part of any other present discs, if that point does exist. The only method I have found is a long and laborious method since it randomly picks a point and checks if it matches my criteria or not. However, in the event where over 99% of the A disc is intersecting with other Bi discs, it evidently is near impossible.
I can't seem to find a better solution. By hand it's simple, but in the discreet domain of algorithms it's harder. Would any of you have an idea?
Here is an illustration of the problem, where the blue section represents the area in which the point can be randomly selected:


I think you'll have more answers if you post your question in the Mathematics Stack Exchange

Your title says you want to find all values in the set, but your body text says you want to find a point. Those are different questions. Edit the post to indicate whether you want to find all points or it suffices to find one point.

I'm trying to get more of a resulting set which all points are part of and from which a specific point can be randomly chosen from if that set is non empty

I'm with @Dima above.  This isn't really a programming question.

An algorithmic way to randomly select a point in the described set is a programming question. It may involve math, and describing the set formally may be math, and the question may benefit from answers both on the Mathematics Stack Exchange and here, but a method for randomly selecting a point is clearly an algorithm issue and hence is a programming question.

Can the answer to this question, which proposes the use of Quadtrees, help you maybe? It is about sampling from the intersection of circles rather than the difference, but it might be adaptable to your problem.

you could use algebra to model the problem and then implement the program

As (probably) the fastest but less accurate approach, you can use OpenCV or Pillow to draw the discs on a mask image as if you were drawing them by hand, then you can extract all the pixels in the target area. You can also use it as a filter before doing accurate calculations, since it can determine if a point matches the criteria in O(1).

I have thought about determining the equations of the uncovered part of the A disk. However, I do not know to easily calculate that equation nor implement it in python.
As I am trying to build a proof-of -concept model, I cannot use graph methods as proposed by Ken and Quadtrees do not seem to be the solution.

We can use shapely to approximate the circles and find the the set differences.  To sample from the resulting difference, we can use the answer from this thread: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69833/
and apply it over each polygon in the multiply difference, weighted by the area of each polygon to distribute the sampled points.
Here we setup a basic circle object and adapt the sampling method to ensure each point is within the polygon.
import random
from collections import Counter
import shapely
from shapely.affinity import affine_transform
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon
from shapely.ops import triangulate


class Circle:
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, radius: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self._geom = Point(x, y).buffer(radius, quad_segs=90)
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'<Circle(x={self.x}, y={self.y}, radius={self.radius})'
    
    def difference(self, other: 'Circle') -> Polygon|MultiPolygon:
        return shapely.difference(self._geom, other._geom).normalize()
    
    def difference_all(self, *others: 'Circle') -> Polygon|MultiPolygon:
        return shapely.difference(
            self._geom, 
            shapely.union_all([o._geom for o in others])
        ).normalize()
    

# adapted from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69833/
def random_points_in_polygon(polygon: Polygon, k: int) -> list[Point]:
    "Return list of k points chosen uniformly at random inside the polygon."
    areas = []
    transforms = []
    for t in triangulate(polygon):
        areas.append(t.area)
        (x0, y0), (x1, y1), (x2, y2), _ = t.exterior.coords
        transforms.append([x1 - x0, x2 - x0, y2 - y0, y1 - y0, x0, y0])
    points = []
    for transform in random.choices(transforms, weights=areas, k=k):
        x, y = [random.random() for _ in range(2)]
        if x + y > 1:
            p = Point(1 - x, 1 - y)
        else:
            p = Point(x, y)
        p_transformed = affine_transform(p, transform)
        if polygon.contains(p_transformed):
            points.append(p_transformed)
    if len(points) < k:
        points.extend(random_points_in_polygon(polygon, k-len(points)))
    return points

Here is where we handle the resulting difference, which can be either a polygon or multipolygon.  If it is a mutlipolyon, the k sample points get distributed to each sub-polygon based on the ratio of the areas.
def sample_difference(ps: Polygon|MultiPolygon, k: int) -> list[Point]:
    """
    Returns k samples from the difference of multiple Circles.
    """
    if isinstance(ps, Polygon):
        ps = MultiPolygon([ps])
    poly_indices = list(range(len(ps.geoms)))
    sample_probs = [p.area / ps.area for p in ps.geoms]
    poly_index_k_map = Counter(random.choices(poly_indices, weights=sample_probs, k=k))

    points = []
    for ix, p in enumerate(ps.geoms):
        k_poly = poly_index_k_map.get(ix, 0)
        if not k_poly:
            continue
        poly_points = random_points_in_polygon(p, k_poly)
        points.extend(poly_points)
    return points

Here is an example:
a = Circle(0, 0, 5.1)
b_list = (
    [Circle(1, i, 1.5) for i in range(-5, 6)]
    + [Circle(-3, i, 1.5) for i in range(-5, 6)]
)
# the difference cuts a into 3 segments
a_blist_diff = a.difference_all(*b_list)
sampled_points = sample_difference(a_blist_diff, 300)

This is what a and b_list look like overlayed:

Here is a_blist_diff:

And this is what the sampled points looks like:


Your solution appears to be more suitable to my problem. I'll test the method and come back to you.

Think about triangles and nothing but triangles. So this is how I would do it:

Build and intersect triangular meshes, at the very end of this you should have your final set of triangles which represents area you would sample from.

Link: https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/

Calculate areas of triangles in the final mesh and build probabilities table

pi = Ai/ Sumi Ai

Use Alias sampling to do fast triangle selection from the probability tables you build. This is fast O(1)
sampling which requires some setup.

Link: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats/sampling_dau.html

Sample uniform from a selected triangle. This is O(1) sampling. See mine and other folks answers there: Generate random locations within a triangular domain

Overall, should be O(1) sampling to get (x,y) point sampled from the area. Smaller triangles will have better quality of sampling, longer setup stage, but about the same sampling speed, thus O(1)
